# Classes allowed in a Win32 DLL?

Tags: winapi, dll, nsis

**Can a NSIS plugin I made contain C++ classes or can it only be C code?**

I am developing a NSIS plugin as a Win32 DLL but I am getting a compile error in my header file at the line where my class is declared.

The compile error is:

> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MyClass'

The line that causes the compile error is:

```
class MyClass
```

Whats going wrong? Am I not allowed classes in a Win32 DLL? I am compiling in MS Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: You can certainly put/use classes in DLLs. Perhaps you're compiling the code as C rather than C++?

Comment: Once you compile, C and C++ are not different. As Jerry said, you must be using a C compiler rather than a C++ compiler.

Comment: The NSIS plugin ABI is just a C function export and it does not care about the internal code in the dll or the language used to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I made this mistake many years ago and spent an hour scratching my head.  I was looking round for a compiler option that would select whether code is compiled as C or C++, but there isn't one that you can select in the IDE (though you can control this from the `cl` command-line using `/Tc` and `/Tp`).  However, the answer is simple.

If a source file has a `.c` extensions it's compiled as C.  If it has a `.cpp` extension it's compiled as C++.

Additionally, if you put C++ constructs (such as classes) in a header file and `#include` them in a C file you'll get the same problem.  You can hide the C++ constructs from C using `#ifdef __cplusplus`.

Comment: There is an option, /Tc vs /Tp

Comment: @HansPassant  So there is!  Though this was VC6, which as far I can tell doesn't let you set arbitrary compiler switches on individual source files.